# Changing the index of the selected element everytime an event is triggered

Tags: jquery

I am trying to increment the index of the selected invoiceLine element everytime this event is triggered. I was wondering if someone can show me a simple way to do this, if it is even possible, as I am new to JQuery and am having a really difficult time with this.

```
$invoiceLine.find('input').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().next().find('div input').removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

Comment: I am trying to increment the index of the selected invoiceLine element everytime the 'change' event is triggered. So basically,  every time the event runs the index of 'this' will be equal to this + 1. So it targets the 'next' element in the DOM everytime it fires.

Comment: Are you trying to say that you want to change which element `$invoiceLine` references? The code you show has no "index" variable(s), so your question doesn't make sense. What do you mean by "selected"?

Comment: With so much `.parent()`, `next()`, `find()`, etc. happening, the HTML **is** relevant.

Comment: JQuery has a thing called a 'selector' which selects an array of elements in the DOM meeting the criteria of this 'selector'. Thats what I mean by 'selected' elements. I am trying to change the index of the element selected every time the event is triggered. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

If by index you mean the position of the element within its siblings, you can easily move elements with many jQuery methods, e.g. after(), before(), insertAfter(), insertBefore(), append(), appendTo(), etc.
Here's a simple example:

HTML:

```
<div class="invoiceLine">
    1 <input />
</div>
<div class="invoiceLine">
    2 <input />
</div>
<div class="invoiceLine">
    3 <input />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.invoiceLine').find('input').change(function() {
    var line = $(this).closest('.invoiceLine'); // find enclosing invoiceLine
    var next = line.next(); // find next invoiceLine
    if (next.length) // check that current line is not last
        line.insertAfter(next); // insert current line after the next one
});​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/antishok/DteuU/

Comment: Then I have absolutely no idea what you're asking for ;)